# Enzyme ReactWrapper not being updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm testing a React application using Enzyme and Jest. The application features a set of checkboxes representing a list of APIs. Every time such a checkbox is clicked (onChange is triggered) its service id is added to the application's State so that the input is rendered *checked*.

```js
state = {
  checkedServicesIds: [] // Array<number>
}
```

The spec:

```js
it.only('should check and uncheck services when clicked', () => {
  wrapper.setProps({ [{ id: 0, name: 'The Super API' }, { id: 1, name: 'Cool Villains Hub' }] })
  wrapper.setState({ checkedServicesIds: [] })

  // Gettings wrappers for each checkbox
  const input0 = wrapper.find(`input#service_ids_${0}`)
  const input1 = wrapper.find(`input#service_ids_${1}`)

  expect(input0.prop('checked')).toBe(false) // --> passes
  expect(input1.prop('checked')).toBe(false) // --> passes

  input0.simulate('change') // Here id: 0 is added to the array

  // wrapper.update() and/or input0.update() does nothing here

  expect(wrapper.state('checkedServicesIds')).toEqual([0]) // --> passes

  // Now here's the thing: the old wrapper did not update
  expect(wrapper.find(`input#service_ids_${0}`).prop('checked')).toBe(true) // --> passes
  expect(input0.prop('checked')).toBe(true) // --> Expected: true, Received: false !!!
})
```

Am I not using `update` correctly?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to update the wrapper.

```
wrapper.update();
```

From [enzyme documentation](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/update.html):

> Forces a re-render. Useful to run before checking the render output if something external may be updating the state of the component somewhere.
>
> NOTE: can only be called on a wrapper instance that is also the root instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, using `wrapper.update()` did not solve the issue. If I reassign `input0 = wrapper.find(`input#user_member_permission_service_ids_${0}`)` it works, even if not updating.

Comment: Oh yes didn't see that only the last test was not passing. I think you can remove all the updates then.